# Checking whether $\frac{e^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}}-e^{\frac{v^{2}t}{2}}-e^{\frac{u^{2}t}{2}}+1 }{te^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}}}$ is decreasing.

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $f(t):=\frac{e^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}}-e^{\frac{v^{2}t}{2}}-e^{\frac{u^{2}t}{2}}+1}{te^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}}}=\frac{1}{t}(1-e^{-\frac{v^{2}t}{2}}-e^{-\frac{u^{2}t}{2}}+e^{-\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}})$, I want to check whether $f(t)\geq f(s)$ for $s>t$ and constants $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Eg. it is true for $(u,v)=(1,1),(2,3)$ and $s=t+1$ by Wolfram.

I was wondering if there is a quick way to see it.

**Attempt**
1)We obviously have $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}(1-e^{-\frac{v^{2}t}{2}}-e^{-\frac{u^{2}t}{2}}+e^{-\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}})\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$.

For s=t+1, this is equivalent to showing that the following is positive

$\frac{e^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})(3t+1)}{2}}-(t+1)e^{\frac{(2u^{2}+3v^{2})t+u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}}-(t+1)e^{\frac{(3u^{2}+2v^{2})t+u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}} +(t+1)e^{\frac{(2u^{2}+2v^{2})t+u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}}+te^{\frac{(2u^{2}+3v^{2})t+v^{2}}{2}}+te^{\frac{(3u^{2}+2v^{2})t+u^{2}}{2}} -te^{\frac{(2u^{2}+2v^{2})t}{2}} }{t(t+1)e^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})(3t+1)}{2}}} = $

$=
\frac{e^{\frac{u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}}
(e^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})t}{2}}-e^{\frac{v^{2}t}{2}}-e^{\frac{u^{2}t}{2}} +1)+
t(1+e^{\frac{v^{2}t+v^{2}}{2}}+e^{\frac{u^{2}t+u^{2}}{2}}+e^{\frac{u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}}-e^{\frac{v^{2}t+u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}}-e^{\frac{u^{2}t+u^{2}+v^{2}}{2}})
}{t(t+1)e^{\frac{(u^{2}+v^{2})(t+1)}{2}}}<0$

because each of the brackets is negative.

So I guess I made a mistake somewhere. This is not homework, so if you have a quick trick feel free to share.

2)
$\frac{f(s)}{f(t)}=
\frac{t}{s}\frac{\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v^2s}{2}}\right)\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{u^2s}{2}}\right)}{\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v^2t}{2}}\right)\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{u^2t}{2}}\right)}$

We have $\frac{t}{s}<1$ but $\frac{\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v^2s}{2}}\right)}{\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v^2t}{2}}\right)}>1$.

3)Negative derivative

By computing this is equivalent to

$e^{t (u^2+v^2)}-(u^2 t+1) e^{v^2 t}-e^{u^2 t} (v^2 t+1)+u^2 t+v^2 t+1$

being positive. I will try this and I will update it.

Comment: Are $u, v$ parameters? Because generally you don't see the concept of "increasing" for functions $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$

Comment: Are you allowed to check if $f'(t) < 0$ for all $t$?

Comment: Also, your "obviously" statement doesn't make sense, "$f(t) \to 0$" on its own is missing information

Comment: for case $u=v=1,f(1)=1+e^{-1}-2e^{-.5},f(2)=0.5+0.5e^{-2}-e^{-1}, f(2)-f(1)=.04>0,f(4)-f(3)=-0.014<0$,so you can see what $f(t)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{t}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{v^2t}{2}}\right)\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{u^2t}{2}}\right)
$$
Is you function so you can try doing it with this rather than your equation? Easier on the bookkeeping. (Unless this was what you were given already
:))

Furthermore it appears to me that  for $t>0$ then $f(t) >0$ $\forall t$.
Thus you have to try and prove that
$$
\frac{f(s)}{f(t)}<1\forall s>t
$$

Comment: You could also manipulate this expressions to get some hyperbolic functions.

Comment: We could but it seems to me easier to check if the function is decreasing with the above (at least to me anyway :))